# ORA-01722: invalid number but datatype is date and it will not accept it in any way

Tags: oracle

Yet another of these issues of not being numeric, just can't figure it out.

My query:

```
SELECT
    s.user_id,
    date_time, 
    to_char(Date_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') timestamp,
        ( SELECT DECODE
        FROM (  SELECT  DECODE, code
                FROM    codelist_decode
                WHERE   codelist_id = 5029
                AND language_code = 001
             ) t5
        WHERE  t5.code = s.operation_type) 
    AS operation,
        ( SELECT t1.module_name_internal
        FROM (  SELECT  module_name_internal, module_id
                FROM    aris_admin_module
              ) t1
        WHERE  s.module_id = t1.module_id
        ) 
    AS module,
    t.session_id,
    t.seq_admin_audit_trail,
    t.record_id,
        ( SELECT t4.field_name_e
          FROM (  SELECT  field_name_e, admin_field_id
                  FROM    aris_admin_table_field
                ) t4
          WHERE admin_field_id = t.field_id) 
    AS field_name,
        ( SELECT t2.DECODE
          FROM  (  SELECT  DECODE, code
                   FROM    aris_admin_audit_decode
                   WHERE   field_id = t.field_id
                ) t2
          WHERE  t2.code = to_number(t.old_value)) 
    AS org_value_yn,
    t.old_value,
        ( SELECT t3.DECODE
          FROM ( SELECT  DECODE, code
                 FROM    aris_admin_audit_decode
                 WHERE   field_id = t.field_id
                ) t3
          WHERE t3.code = to_number(t.new_value)) 
    AS new_value_yn
    ,t.new_value
FROM
    system_admin_audit_session   s,
    system_admin_audit_trail     t
WHERE s.session_id = t.session_id
--order by TO_NUMBER('s.session_id','9999999999')
--or order by to_date(s.date_time) 
order by 2
```

The above generates the error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.

I've tried on ordering on several other columns but same issue.

If I simplify the query it works fine:

```
select s.user_id,s.date_time
from ARISG_PROD.system_admin_audit_session s
order by 2 desc
```

So why is it not recognizing my datetime as date and accepts the ordering?

Comment: If `s.date_time` is already of DATE datatype, **don't** use `to_date()` on it. That would mean Oracle would need to perform an implicit conversion to a VARCHAR2 and then back to DATE. If you want to remove the time portion of the date column, use `trunc()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I can help you here.
Normally, such an error can occur when a string is being compared to a number.

So, foe example if s.module_id was a varchar2 and t1.module_id was defined as a number, the statement like this

```
s.module_id = t1.module_id
```

could be the root cause.

I'd recomment you to comment out all the subqueries in the main select statement and try the query whether the error occurs.

Once the error is gone you have to analyze the comparison statement. Or post it here and we'll have a look

Comment: Interesting, when I remove the decode subqueries org_value_yn and  new_value_yn then it works.
I've also tried to put alias on the subquery from table, but that still did not work.
However, I can live without the decoding part, so that's fine. 
Thanks for your help. (I still don't quite get it though :o) )

Comment: I guess it's the conversion here that messes things up: t2.code = to_number(t.old_value))

Comment: @kristian there are 3 another suspects here: 1) codelist_id = 5029; 2) language_code = 001; 3) field_id = t.field_id

Try to play with all the 4 just commenting them out step by step. The you'll find the bastard!

Comment: The other 3 works well, it's only the 2 to_number conversions I need to filter out.
I can use the output without the decodes :)

Comment: @kristian anyway glad to hear my idea helped.